How to CCTV ray portal?
In Blender 4.2, there is a new node Ray Portal BSDF.
How can I ray portal from an empty (FROM) to another empty (TO) like CCTV on screen example?
Nodes

There is a plane next to Suzanne's head, offset on x axis (to the right). FROM empty in top left. TO empty in front of Suzanne.

Render

Wanted render
Plane with portal BSDF, with view from FROM empty (top) to TO empty (in front of Suzanne)

